# How to Install Custom Extension in Isolated VsShell (Visual Studio 2015 - Isolated Shell)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vsix, vsx, visual-studio-shell

I have developed a app with help of Visual Studio 2015 - Isolated Shell SDK and now want to install a custom extension package (VSIX) and Project Type and template (VSIX) but not able to install them even i have enabled extension and update Tool menu.

Comment: You need to address the name and version of your extension and maybe install for all users - so please share your extension manifest file

Comment: Please double click the file named source.extension.vsixmanifest -> Install Targets -> check if Identifier is match with your Isolated VsShell, for more information, please refer to: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/33fcbda1-9bab-4266-b7ed-89775456ac38/how-to-register-vspackage-in-visual-studio-isolated-shell?forum=vsx